# Wrap the content of text view in java code in android

Tags: android

I am dynamically creating layout and text view in android. If the text view content is large, how to wrap the content of text view dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a TextView wrap it's content you have to specify that it should not be treated as 'single line'. You can do this in it's XML properties or dynamically by callig:

```
public void setSingleLine (boolean singleLine)
```

*If true, sets the properties of this field (lines, horizontally scrolling, transformation method) to be for a single-line input; if false, restores these to the default conditions. Note that calling this with false restores default conditions, not necessarily those that were in effect prior to calling it with true.*

**Related XML Attributes**

- android:singleLine

An example:

```
value.setSingleLine(false);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html